# Updating or adding keys to dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, bigdata

I have many dicts, I'm giving 2 for this example:

```
dict1={'green': 3, 'yellow': 5, 'blue': 1}
dict2={'green': 5, 'yellow': 1, 'blue': 3, 'purple': 10}
```

I've been trying to find a way to add the 2 dicts so i can have updated values(sum) for existing keys, and added up keys and values for non-existant ones.

Results:

```
results = {'green': 8, 'yellow': 6, 'blue': 4, 'purple': 10}
```

I tried `dict1.update(dict2)` but as you know , I've only got a dictionary with updated values, not summed up.

Any ways to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

Solved : Actually collections.Counter did the trick ... Thanks

Comment: use a collections.Counter.

Comment: What do you want to happen for duplicate keys? For instance, do you want 'green' to be mapped to 3, 5, 3+5, or something else?

Comment: @KyleStrand: 3 + 5, see the example `results` dictionary.

Comment: @mgilson Thanks collections.Counter did it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, that's surprisingly hard...

```
dicts = [dict1, dict2]
dict([(key, sum(map(lambda x: x.get(key) or 0, dicts))) for key in set(reduce(lambda a,b: a + b, map(lambda x: x.keys(), dicts), []))])
```

[{'blue': 1, 'green': 3, 'yellow': 5}, {'blue': 3, 'purple': 10, 'green': 5, 'yellow': 1}]

Or more readable

```
dicts = [dict1, dict2]
keys = reduce(lambda a,b: a + b, map(lambda x: x.keys(), dicts), [])
dict([(key, sum(map(lambda x: x.get(key) or 0, dicts))) for key in set(keys)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{x: dict1.get(x,0) + dict2.get(x,0) for x in set(dict1.keys() + dict2.keys())}
```

Output:

```
{'blue': 4, 'purple': 10, 'green': 8, 'yellow': 6}
```